# Using c# in aspx page to only display if > 0

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

```
<div style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0; border:1px solid;  border-color:#EBEBFF; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px;"><%:NumerofDeliveries%></div>
```

ATM my div will display the 'NumberOfDeliveries'. I want to change this to only show if >0.

I tried...

```
   <% if (NumerofDeliveries > 0) %>
    <% { %>
    <% <div style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0; border:1px solid;  border-color:#EBEBFF; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px;"><%:NumerofDeliveries%></div> %> 
    <% } %>
```

but im getting errors about expected semi-colans.
Also the `<%:NumerofDeliveries%>` is throwing the same problem with missing `;`

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe add a `;`. If only someone had made the error message say exactly what you needed to do......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familar with native MVC syntax (razor mainly), but I suspect you need to take the HTML markup out of the code blocks:

```
<% if (NumerofDeliveries > 0) %>
<% { %>
<div style="position:absolute; right:0; top:0; border:1px solid;  border-color:#EBEBFF; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px;"><%:NumerofDeliveries%></div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: This isn't the Razor syntax, this is the 'legacy' ASP.NET inline WebForms script carry on.

Comment: @GrantThomas Sorry perhaps my answer wasn't clear enough. I was stating that I'm not familiar with the legacy syntax, I'm only familiar with the Razor syntax. However I've had a 'guess' at what the issue probably is from my WebForms experience.

Answer (score 2):

You should give the `<div>` an ID and then set it visible in `Page_Load` event. Suppose your div-id is `"a"` then write this code on `Page_Load`:

```
if(NumerofDeliveries > 0)
{
    a.visible=true;
}
else
{
    a.visible=false;
}
```